# Advice on most conventional method of parsing data from an input file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a somewhat novice writer of Excel Macros for people in my company.  I can tackle the issue at hand in a few different ways but would like some advice on the most efficient and conventional manner to do so.

The macro needs to retrieve data from an input file and compare this data to other data from a second input file.  These files are consistent in their structure but obviously different in the data they contain.  Each file may contain information for up to 96 samples.  Each sample has ~20 categories of information and each category may have 10 pieces of data.  So, each sample could have up to 200 pieces of data tied to it.

It seems to me that the best way to store this information is to either create a Class to define an Object and then have a Collection of those Objects like:

```
Dim Samples as Collection
Dim Smp as CSample

Set Samples = New Collection

For x = 1 to NumberOfSamplesInFile
   Set Smp = New CSample
   'Set the properties of Smp for each piece of data
   Samples.Add Smp
Next x
```

I assume that I can have certain properties of Smp be arrays? I.e. can a property of the Class be defined as:

```
Private pSampleID as String
Private pAreaUnderCurve(1 to 10) as double
Private pRetentionTime(1 to 10) as double
```

Such that

```
Smp.SampleID = "XYZ"
```

but

```
Smp.AreaUnderCurve(1) = 1234
Smp.AreaUnderCurve(2) = 2345
Smp.AreaUnderCurve(3) = 123.78
```

and the same for retention time (different values obviously)?

The other way I imagined doing this is with the Type declaration:

```
Type Sample
   SampleID as String
   AreaUnderCurve(1 to 10) as double
   RetentionTime(1 to 10) as double
End Type
```

My questions is which way is most conventional/recommended?

Answer (score 1):

you could also import the two files into excel in 2 worksheets, then run a comparison on them either by looping through or putting in formulae to match the records and highlight unmatched data...

Is the format of the data files suitable for being imported into Excel?

Comment: The files are somewhat suitable to be imported into Excel except I'll be outputting a completely different file with only a subset of the data (and calculation will be applied to the data).  It seemed to me that importing the files into Excel is just one extra step to parsing out the information I need.  I would possibly still need to setup an Object or Type or 2D array to deal with all the data I need.   I'm also trying to make this useable for other macros that I may possibly write in the future.as these output files are standard by instrument.

Comment: Perhaps you could query the files as tables using the ADO and OLEDB Text File driver, and use your SQL Query to get you the needed information See the MSDN article: [Much ADO About Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)

Comment: hmm... I do like that suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Philip or even bring the two files into access then make all your comparisons with very minimal coding. Possibly none... Import from file to two tables, and make your output from a query.